# iphone - store id/value pairs in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a php file which returns XML with id/value pairs.
When I parse the XML I create an array of objects each having an id and a value.
What I do now is add the value from the XML to the cell text. Also want to store the corresponding ID, so I can use it in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.
I'm very new to the iPhone, so this might be obvious, sorry :)

Currently my cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks like this:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    int categoryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[categories objectAtIndex: categoryIndex] objectForKey: @"CategoryName"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    return cell;

}
```

The category object is defined like so:

```
category = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[category setObject:currentID forKey:@"CategoryId"];
        [category setObject:currentName forKey:@"CategoryName"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to add the actual ID to the cell.

If you map the objects in your array to the UITableView 1:1 and your Table only has 1 group, you can just use the IndexPath's row as an index to the NSArray to retrieve the correct entry.

The first cell of your table will have `row => 0` and the object corresponding to it in your array will also have the index of `0`.

If you have several groups, then I assume your array will contain several sub-arrays to represent this. In that case, use the group portion of the IndexPath to jump to the right array and the row portion to jump to the right entry.

**Alternative:**

If you must for some reason include the ID in the actual cell, sublcass `UITableViewCell` and add a single NSNumber `cellID` to its interface.

Make sure to retain it in the property declaration and synthesize it.

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath(), add

```
cell.cellID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:YOURID];
```

This way you can later retrieve the `cellID` from the actual cell within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thank you! I would actually opt for subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your didSelect method.

```
int categoryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
NSString *id = [[categories objectAtIndex:categoryIndex] objectForKey: @"CategoryId"];
```